# Android actionbar tab icon png dimensions

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, android-icons

What should the dimensions of the actionbar **tab** icon be? (meaning, mostly, size in pixels and padding)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_tab.html

Comment: @TomerMor: Those are for `TabHost`, not the action bar.

Comment: I've been wrestling with this problem for a few hours. I suspect that the pixel dimensions for an action bar tab icon are the same as those for the other action bar icons. The problem seems to be that if the drawn area is centred in the image, it collides with the tab indicator area that comes from the 9-patch used as the background. I've resorted to inspecting those 9-patches and reducing the height of the drawn area to preserve margins.

Comment: @CommonsWare  It specifically says "Action Bar" on that webpage for Iconography.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: That page changed in the past 16 months. The page now has no advice at all for any tab icons, other than a naming convention.

Comment: @CommonsWare  It redirects to Iconography.  I am looking at that page at this very moment, and in front of my eyes there is a section: "Action Bar" - which says "Sizes & scale" and specifies 32x32 dp.  I am assuming we are looking at the same link: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: The question is about the "actionbar tab icon". The word "tab" is bolded in the question. If you search that page, you will see that the only reference to tab icons comes in the section on naming conventions.

Comment: I'm still confused.  What should the tab icons be?  That webpage specifically states 32x32dp.  Am I misreading it??

Answer (score 0):

It depends on device screen density which is activity running on. Usual icon sizes are <strike>36x36 px, 48x48 px, 72x72 px, 96x96 px.</strike> <strike>18x18 px, 24x24 px, 36x36 px, 48x48 px</strike>
48x48 px, 32x32 px, 24x24 px

Try this: <strike>http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#size</strike>

<strike>http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar.html#icon11</strike>
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_tab.html#icon5

Comment: Note that your link is to launcher icons, not action bar tab icons.

Comment: I think that action bar icons are same as launcher icons, aren't they?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar.html#icon11

Comment: @tomasbuzek - Both links you posted do not discuss TAB icons.

Comment: Tab icons on developers.android.com: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_tab.html#icon5

Comment: @tomasbuzek - The last link refers to the OLD tabs mechanism out of the actionbar context.